# Django rest framework ```TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int``` being thrown

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, typeerror

I have a `SMSMessages` model that will contain all the sms sent.I'm trying access via the django-rest-framework `ListCreateAPIView` class, but I keep on hitting error when I try to do an `OPTION` request on the api via Insomnia, `TypeError at /smsmessages/
type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int`.

I searched on SO and found similar errors but they were caused b/c of a `filter()` argument, which doesn't apply to this.
I'm using django 2.2.5, python 3.6.8, django-rest-framework 3.10.3 and a mysqlclient 1.4.4.

this is the model of `SMSMessages`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class SMSMessages(models.Model):
    sms_number_to = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    sms_content = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    sending_user = models.ForeignKey("SMSUser", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="user_that_sent", limit_choices_to=1)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    delivery_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "SMSMessages"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sending_user
```

and this is this the urls.py file:

```py
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from notification.apiviews import SMSendView, SMSMessagesView

app_name = "notification"

router = DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    path("smsmessages/", SMSMessagesView.as_view(), name="sms_messages"),
]
```

so the way I access it is by sending an OPTION request to `http://localhost:8000/smsmessages/`.
This the SMSMessagesview class that is used for the api view:

```py
from rest_framework import generics, status, viewsets, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

from commons.models import SMSMessages
from commons.serializers import SMSMessagesSerializer


class SMSMessagesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    """
    This class is responsible for generating, and returning, the view for all created objects of the SMSMessages model.
    It sub-classes the ListCreateAPIView class from the generics module.
    """
    queryset = SMSMessages.objects.all()
    if not queryset:
        Response(data={"{0} not found".format(queryset)}, status=404, content_type="application/json")

    serializer_class = SMSMessagesSerializer
```

and this is the error:

```py
TypeError at /notification/smsmessages/
type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int

Request Method: OPTIONS
Request URL: http://localhost:8055/notification/smsmessages/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Executable: /home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path: ['/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et', '/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python36.zip', '/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6', '/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time: Sat, 5 Oct 2019 16:19:59 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_swagger',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'commons',
 'notification']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in options
  516.         data = self.metadata_class().determine_metadata(request, self)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in determine_metadata
  68.             actions = self.determine_actions(request, view)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in determine_actions
  94.                 actions[method] = self.get_serializer_info(serializer)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py" in get_serializer_info
  111.             for field_name, field in serializer.fields.items()

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  80.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in fields
  360.         for key, value in self.get_fields().items():

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in get_fields
  1047.                 source, info, model, depth

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in build_field
  1182.                 return self.build_relational_field(field_name, relation_info)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in build_relational_field
  1257.         field_kwargs = get_relation_kwargs(field_name, relation_info)

File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py" in get_relation_kwargs
  255.             limit_choices_to = models.Q(**limit_choices_to)

Exception Type: TypeError at /notification/smsmessages/
Exception Value: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int
```

This is the serializer class used:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

from commons.models import SMSUser, SMSPrice, Type, SMSMessages

class SMSMessagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A class for serializing the SMSMessages model's data. It sub-classes the
    ModelSerializer class from serializer's module.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = SMSMessages
        fields = '__all__'
```

This same error is raised when I try to add an `SMSMessages` object to the db via the admin interface. Can anybody help?

Comment: error in serialization of related object . i think .

Comment: @NaveenJain I don't think so, I've updated the question and inserted the serializer and, with the exception of it targeting this above model, it similar to another one I used that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for ForeignKey.limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to), it...

> sets a limit to the available choices for this field when this field is rendered using a ModelForm or the admin (by default, all objects in the queryset are available to choose). Either a dictionary, a Q object, or a callable returning a dictionary or Q object can be used.

...but in the model, you set an integer `limit_choices_to=1` which is none of these things.

Did you perhaps intend to use something like `limit_choices_to={'id': 1}` to limit choices to SMS users with that ID?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I thought ```limit_choices_to``` was literally used to limit the choices returned that's why I gave it an integer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That's just because you use [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) with wrong data format which defined by Django.

> Either a dictionary, a Q object, or a callable returning a dictionary or Q object can be used.

So this caused the error:

```
sending_user = models.ForeignKey("SMSUser", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="user_that_sent", limit_choices_to=1 # HERE)
```

So you might need to be clear what you want to do here to config the right filter so that Django Admin will will filter data when you select `sending_user` for your model. Like if you want to allow to select `is_superuser` only for `sending_user` on admin page then you can go with this:

```
limit_choices_to={
    'is_superuser': True,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I do have one question, if it won't be a bother, what if I wanted to allow it to select the actual company of the user that sent it (the company is saved in the user table)?

Comment: I'm not so clear about that, you mean only allow to select **sending_user** who has the same company name as the user who are using the admin page?

Comment: No, something like ```sending_user = models.ForeignKey("SMSUser", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="user_that_sent", limit_choices_to={'company_name'})```. Is that possible?

Comment: No, I think it's not. It should come with a value you want to filter, like if you want to only allow users which have `company_name` is Google then it suppose to be like this `limit_choices_to={'company_name': 'Google'}`.

Comment: Because that foreign key is linked to User model so it will be a user instead of a `company_name`.

Comment: Hmm but I want the model to contain more than one company name but I see your point. I guess I can do that from the ```apiviews``` module instead of the ```models``` module. Thank you very much for all your help.